# On the abscissa of convergence of a Dirichlet series.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I am trying to find the abscissa of convergence of the Dirichlet series for the arithmetic function $|\mu(n)|$.

I have managed to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}.$$

Then it is easy to see that the abscissa of convergence of the above Dirichlet series is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Is this right or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Given a Dirichlet series $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$, the *abscissa of convergence* $σ_0$ is defined to be the infimum of all $\mathrm{Re}(s)$ such that $f(s)$ is convergent.

Comment: $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$

Comment: even directly note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\mu(n)|}{n} \ge \sum_p\frac{1}{p} = \infty$ where $p$ prime

Comment: @reuns Right, so then the abscissa of convergence would be 1?

Comment: What is the definition of "abscissa of convergence" that you are using? Have you tried applying that definition to this Dirichlet series? If so, what is the point that's confusing you?

Comment: @GregMartin My bad, I should have made it more clear! Given a Dirichlet series $f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$, the abscissa of convergence $\sigma_0$ is defined to be the infimum of all $\mathrm{Re}(s)$ such that $f(s)$ is convergent.

Comment: A result on the existence of abscissa of convergence shows that if $\mathrm{Re}(s)>\sigma_0$, then $f(s)$ converges. So based on my result and @reuns comment, wouldn't $\sigma_0=1$ in this case?

Comment: Yes it converges for $\Re(s) > 1$ due to $|\mu(n)|\le 1$ and it diverges at $s=1$ (or as $s\to 1^+$) due to the pole. So $\sigma_0=1$.

Comment: @reuns Great, thanks! Apologies for the confusion earlier.

Comment: Or perhaps better, due to the pole it is unbounded as $s\to 1^+$. Due to the non-negative coefficients if it was convergent at $1-\epsilon$ then it would be bounded on $s\ge 1-\epsilon$ (the non-negative coefficients assumption is unecessary to have the boundedness, that's another theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well known theorem of Landau shows that a Dirichlet series with positive coefficients will have a pole at $s = \sigma_0$, where $\mathrm{Re} s = \sigma_0$ is the abscissa of convergence. It is clear from your expression that the first pole of this series is at $s = 1$, and thus the abscissa of convergence is $1$.

A different perspective is to consider what the Dirichlet series represents. The average order of $\lvert \mu(n) \rvert$ is $6/\pi^2$. This is because
$$\sum_{n \leq X} \mu(n) $$
counts the number of of squarefree integers up to $X$. Partial summation then implies that the Dirichlet series can't converge if $\mathrm{Re} s < 1$. Conversely, it's straightforward to show that the series converges for $\mathrm{Re} s > 1$ by comparison with the Riemann zeta function.